# What happened to my Emacs? It doesn't auto-indent or detect parentheses correctly anymore

Tags: emacs, indentation, parentheses, auto-indent

I worked in Emacs at a company for a few years. It worked just fine. For a given mode, it would automatically indent the next lines where they should be (or could be, in the case of Python). <s>When typing a closing parenthesis, bracket, or brace, it would highlight the corresponding opening one.</s>

I took a break from that company for a few months, and now I'm back. Emacs no longer indents automatically for any file or mode; each new line starts at the beginning of the line. <s>The parenthesis highlighting also only highlights the latest opening parenthesis no matter how many closing parentheses I type.</s>

Nothing seems to have changed for anyone else; just me. What can I do to fix it?

Using `global-set-key (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)` in my .emacs file helps somewhat, but the behavior is entirely off and annoying.

---

**Edit:** The parenthesis matching problem has been solved. The show-paren-mode has been disabled by default, so I added `(show-paren-mode 1)` to my .emacs file.

Comment: Well, is the Emacs version the same?  Is your `.emacs` the same?  Are the installed packages (that do not ship with Emacs) the same?  Is the OS that Emacs is on the same?  Did you backup your `.emacs` and/or entire Emacs installation somewhere when it was working?  Have you Googled different types of parentheses highlighting packages as well as the default behavior for parentheses highlighting?  [That way, you can probably determine what you were using to produce the type of parentheses highlighting that you prefer.]

Comment: The Emacs version is the same. The .emacs files were never touched until I tried the global-set-key above; all users' .emacs files are identical and nearly empty. The OS is the same (Debian), but this is also occurring on a new Redhat 7.4 server. I am not aware of using any particular packages; I assumed it was all default behavior since it worked the same way at my college and in both Linux laptops I have set up myself in the past. I never touched those .emacs files, either. I just found that show-paren-mode is now disabled by default for some reason, so I fixed that; I'll update my post.

Comment: Good luck! In short, a few things need to happen: (1) Emacs needs to understand the indentation rules for your language, e.g. it needs to be in `python-mode` or `py-mode` or whatever the one you were using was. (2) The mode will define a few things, like rebinding the meaning of `RET`, and so on. Without these, even with `newline-and-indent`, there may not be enough information to know how to indent.

Comment: My problem is that Emacs seems to be missing that kind of information for all the modes. Python, HTML, Java, C, JavaScript, CSS... Everything I try fails to indent at all.

Comment: Seems worth a bug report.